# how to convert DTM to TDM in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I saved 2 files on disk using `save` function. The first one is TDM object from `tm` package. It looks this way in environment:

[image]

The second one is DTM, but the difference is I wrapped it with `as.matrix` function, so it looks like:

[image]

My question is, how to convert this second object to the first one. Simply transpose doesn't work, I need to 'unmatrix' it somehow. Is it possible? Or should I re-create the object once again which is quite long process, because the data in both is much different, as you can see in the parameters. Thanks.

Comment: Never use `as.matrix` with a DocumentTermMatrix, especially of that size. You could easily run out of memory. Try `t(as.DocumentTermMatrix(slam::as.simple_triplet_matrix(content.dtm),weighting=identity))`

Comment: Side note: Screenshots are usually frowned upon. It might be better to post an actual example (like in the answer). Although I know that it might be hard to create sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude) 
m <- as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(crude))

tdm2 <- as.TermDocumentMatrix(t(m), weighting = weightTf) 
identical(tdm, tdm2)
# [1] TRUE
```